# HTTP::Request::UnsupportedSchemeError -- Rails -- HTTP gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using Rails 4.2, HTTP gem, Grape for API.
I'm trying to send request to other website and felt [HTTP gem](https://github.com/httprb/http) is really awesome!

When I try to request a predefined URL, it works fine. But if I want to dynamically request the URL on various parameters. Say for example, I want to take it from ActiveRecord. like

```
url = Users.find_by_id(1).url
```

And I should be able to send a request to that URL.

But I'm unable to do so. 
It throws an error:

```
HTTP::Request::UnsupportedSchemeError
```

Working code :

```
 HTTP.get("https://google.com")
```

I want to dynamically change that "https://google.com" to my URL.

Any workaround mates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad.

It was a simple mistake on my side. The parameters were being parsed correctly.
Missed the "http://" in the parameters everytime. So it was throwing an error. 
Just in case if someone does something silly like this, I'm adding the solution.